# How to open or convert .xwd image dump?

Tags: macos, graphics, screen-capture, file-conversion

I did the image dump of an X window by using `/opt/X11/bin/xwd`, e.g.:

```
xwd -root -silent > screen.xwd
```

Now, how do I open this file or convert into JPEG file?

Probably I could use `pnmtojpeg`, but it seems it is not available in Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use ImageMagick which support jpeg, png and other popular formats, example usage:

```
import -window root screen.jpeg
```

<sup>Install by `brew install imagemagick --with-x11`</sup>